# Combining two optionals, cleanest way to write?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Suppose I have:

```
public void func(){
  Optional<Integer> firstRequiredOptional = ...
  Optional<Integer> secondRequiredOptional = ...

  if(firstRequiredOptional.isPresent() && secondRequiredOptional.isPresent()){
     // do something with values of BOTH optionals
  }

  // Do nothing
}
```

This function will only execute the `if` if BOTH the optionals are present.

I am trying to think of a cleaner way (perhaps function `ifPresent` type) way of writing this, or converting it somehow into `Optional<Integer, Integer>` with both the ints in one optional if possible?

What is the cleaner way to write this?

Comment: @rkosegi: No, that's not what's being asked here.

Comment: @rkosegi No, it wouldn't. The question is not about chaining them but using them both at the same time.

Comment: Why do you think it's not clean?

Comment: What ever the code you have seems to be clean way for me

Comment: I think it is opinion based as "cleaner" is different to everyone. Another option would be to make the if statement like `if(Stream.of(firstRequiredOptional, secondRequiredOptional).allMatch(Optional::isPresent))` but it is matter of opinion and creates intermediate stream (performance).

Comment: you can do this: `if(Stream.of(firstRequiredOptional,secondRequiredOptional)
                .filter(Optional::isPresent).count() == 2){...}`

Comment: It is OK as it is.

Comment: It does exactly what it needs (no more, no less), it's fast, it's easy to read. But people prefer complicated expressions.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `if` statement is already cleaner than the other alternatives.

#### alternative 1

You can use `ifPresent` such as:

```
firstRequiredOptional.ifPresent(first ->
        secondRequiredOptional.ifPresent(second -> something(first, second)));
```

#### alternative 2

Use `allMatch` with `Stream` in case you don't want to consume the values(not that its not possible) such as:

```
if (Stream.of(firstRequiredOptional, secondRequiredOptional)
        .allMatch(Optional::isPresent)) {
    something(); // or something(firstRequiredOptional.get(), secondRequiredOptional.get()); 
}
```

Comment: @Olivier It's not. Updated in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "cleaner."

An `ifPresent` solution, as @Naman points out, looks like:

```
firstRequiredOptional.ifPresent(firstValue ->
    secondRequiredOptional.ifPresent(secondValue -> {
        // do something with firstValue, secondValue.
    }));
```

This is "cleaner" in the sense that you don't have to call both `.isPresent()` and `.get()` on the two optionals.

There's no `Optional<FirstType, SecondType>`, but if the combination of these two required values has some kind of meaning, you might want to embody this in a class.

```
Optional<FullName> fullNameOptional = firstNameOptional.flatMap(firstName ->
    secondNameOptional.map(secondName -> new FullName(firstName, secondName));
fullNameOptional.ifPresent(fullName -> {
    // do something with fullName.
});
```

This has the advantage of giving you a single Optional value you can work with, passing to helper methods, etc., and it follows the Command-Query Separation pattern, which tends to have advantages when debugging and breaking your code down into pieces that are simple to unit-test. But it's not "cleaner" in the sense that you're using less code, for example.

If you like the idea of mapping to a single `Optional`, but don't want to create a type just for this purpose, you can create general-purpose Tuple classes (or use one of several popular Tuple libraries).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a generic aproach for two Optionals:

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

public class OptionalUtils {

    public static <T> void ifPresent(Optional<T> optional1, Optional<T> optional2, BiConsumer<T, T> consumer) {
        if (optional1.isPresent() && optional2.isPresent()) {
            consumer.accept(optional1.get(), optional2.get());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Optional<Integer> test1 = Optional.of(1);
        Optional<Integer> test2 = Optional.of(2);

        ifPresent(test1, test2, (a, b) -> {
            System.out.println(" a + b =" + (a + b));
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if cleaner, but my intuitive solution is to provide a container and use `ofNullable`.

This might be something along the lines of:

```
public class DualOptional<T, K>
    {
        Optional<T> opt1 = Optional.empty();
        Optional<K> opt2 = Optional.empty();

        DualOptional( T t, K k )
        {
            opt1 = Optional.ofNullable( t );
            opt2 = Optional.ofNullable( k );
        }

        public boolean isPresent()
        {
            return opt1.isPresent() && opt2.isPresent();
        }
    }
```

This of course can be expanded to include getters and whatever other functionality is needed.